# How to show/hide reactstrap navbar in Reactjs Redux application?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, reactstrap

I want to show/hide the navigation bar depending upon logged in status of the user. Once the user is authenticated, I store the access-token in local storage. I have tried to show/hide the navigation bar by checking if access-token exists or not. But it needs a hard refresh.

Please find the header component: /components/app-header.js

```
const AppHeader = () => (
    <Navbar color="light" light expand="md">
        <NavbarBrand href="/">TestBrand</NavbarBrand>
        <Nav navbar>
            <NavItem>
                <Link className="lnk" to='/users'>Users</Link>
            </NavItem>            
        </Nav>
        <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
            <NavItem>
                <Link className="lnk" to='/logout'>Logout</Link>
            </NavItem>
        </Nav>
    </Navbar>
)
```

The file which handles all the routes is as below (routes/index.js):

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AppHeader } from '../components';

export default () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            {
                localStorage.getItem('access-token') &&
                <div>
                    <AppHeader />
                </div>
            }
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
                <Route exact path="/users/add" component={Users} />
                <Route exact path="/users/:id" component={Users} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
)
```

The main App just contains the following code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Routes from '../routes';
import '../style.css';

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Routes />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

I do not want to refresh the page, as it defeats the very purpose of SPA. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Make Routes a stateful Component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AppHeader } from '../components';

class Routes {
   this.state = {loggedIn: false}
   componentDidMount() {
     if(localStorage.getItem('access-token')) {
        this.setState({loggedIn: true})
     }
     //attach an event listener to the window object for storage event. 
     $(window).on('storage',() => {
        if(localStorage.getItem('access-token')) {
          this.setState({loggedIn: true})
        }
     });
   } 
   render() {
     return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            {
                this.state.loggedIn &&
                <div>
                    <AppHeader />
                </div>
            }
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/users" component={Users} />
                <Route exact path="/users/add" component={Users} />
                <Route exact path="/users/:id" component={Users} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>)
   }
}
export default Routes;
```

After the component is mounted you are listening to localStorage updates. if local storage is changed it will update the state of the component as required.

Comment: I made it a statefull component. Initialized `isLoggedIn` flag in the state to false. On successfull login I would set it to true and on logout update it back to false. But neither componentDidMount nor componentWillReceiveProps is getting called. In between the Users main component is also getting called. So, I guess need to find better solution.

Comment: How do I make use of HOC pattern combined with React Router?